Given a negative eigenvalue for $L$, can we find $u$ so that $L(u)<0$ pointwise
Let $(M,g)$ be a closed Riemannian manifold. Let $L(u)=-\Delta u+c(x)u$ and $(\lambda_1,u_1)$ be its first eigenvalue/eigenfunction. If $\lambda_1<0$, we have that $\int_{M}u_1L(u_1)<0$. My question is:
If $\lambda_1<0$, an we find a function $u$ so that $u\geq 0$ and $L(u)\leq 0$ pointwise?
Actually I'm working on an unstable minimal surface $\Sigma$, and I'm wondering if I could perturb it to $\Sigma'$ so that $H\leq 0$ everywhere on $\Sigma'$.
Thanks in advance for any help.
